# Shorthand Shortcircut. Is it possible to do some stuff

Tags: javascript, typescript, short-circuit-evaluation

This question is about a TypeScript code-base, but the general concepts that underpin it are ECMAScript concepts, therefore; I have tagged the question as both JS & TS. If I should tag it differently, you can either let me know, or make the edit yourself and I will accept it if I see it.

In a TypeScript document, I have defined an object-type that contains 4 `string` typed properties.

###### *Here is an example of the type*

```
    type StrObjType = {
        foo?: string;
        boo?: string;
        fuz?: string;
        buz?: string;
    }
```

Along with the object described above, I have a function — *its called `funkyFunc`* — with a parameter that takes an argument of type `StrObjType`.

###### *This is what the function looks like:*

```
    function funkyFunc(obj:StrObjType)
    {
        let mesg = '';
        
        if(obj.foo){ mesg += '\n Foo: ' + obj.foo; }
        if(obj.boo){ mesg += '\n Boo: ' + obj.boo; }
        if(obj.fuz){ mesg += '\n Fuz: ' + obj.fuz; }
        if(obj.buz){ mesg += '\n Buz: ' + obj.buz; }
        
        if(!mesg) return '';

        // If a string was concatenated to mesg, return w/ newline appended
        return mesg + '\n';
    }
```

##### About the Function

---

If you can't tell by looking at it, the function creates a list using only properties that were added to the functions object-argument. The new-lines (`'\n'`) are added as a means to format the list.

You can see in the function that each property in the object's type is checked for a truthy value. When a property is truthy, the props string-value is appended to the `mesg` variable via the *"Addition Assignment Operator"*.

##### About the Problem & Solution

---

What I'd like to know, is if there is a better way to write the if statements, if I can short circuit them, or use a shorthand. **[Here is an example of a short circuit that uses nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment#short-circuit_evaluation)**. The link shows a short circuit used to check an objects property, and assign it, only if the property is non-nullish *(null or undefined)*. I was hoping to use that operator, but becauese I am appending the value when the property exist, rather than assigning it, the nullish coalescing won't seem to work.
Nevertheless, I can't help but to feel like this is the ideal situation for implementing a short circuit, but if there is a better way to write the function, I can't figure out what it is.

#### There is this way of writing it, but IDK if it's better.

```
        let mesg = '';

        mesg += obj.foo ? '\n Foo: ' + obj.foo : undefined;
        mesg += obj.boo ? '\n Boo: ' + obj.boo : undefined;
        mesg += obj.fuz ? '\n Fuz: ' + obj.fuz : undefined;
        mesg += obj.buz ? '\n Buz: ' + obj.buz : undefined;

        if (!mesg) return '';

        return mesg + '\n';
    }
```

The problem with the above method of writing the function is that it requires using the **JS built-in `undefined` constant**, and that feels hacky to me, as the `undefined` constant wouldn't be needed otherwise. I could replace the `undefined` constant with an empty string I guess, but it still doesn't feel right, as it requires adding a nullish value, which are values I typically try to avoid (not that I see any immediate harm that comes from using `undefined`, or `''`).

###### So I guess my question is this...

Is there a shorthand, or short-circuit I can use to eliminate the if  keywords in the first function example I added? The short circuit or shorthand cannot be the ternary example I already provided, and it needs to shorten the codes length, or improve the codes readability.

---

If there is any confusion, or if the question just isn't making sense, let me know, I will clear things up. I am peer reviewed, and I feel like there is something I am missing here. I would like to feel more confident about how I am authoring this function.

Comment: The immediate harm from `undefined` is that `'' + undefined` results in the string `'undefined'` - not what you want. So yes, go for the empty string instead.

Comment: No, this cannot be improved with short-circuiting or nullish-coalescing: since you do want to *conditionally* append the linebreak and label next to the value itself, the clearest and cleanest way to do that is an `if` statement. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Awesome, 2bh confirmation that I couldn't do any better is just as helpful. Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is this way of writing it, but IDK if it's better.

What you have after the text above will result in the string `"undfined"` appearing in `mesg`, which I assume you don't want. :-) If you wanted to do it that way, you'd use `""`, not `undefined`, for the third operand of the conditional operators:

```
mesg += obj.foo ? "\n Foo: " + obj.foo : "";
mesg += obj.boo ? "\n Boo: " + obj.boo : "";
mesg += obj.fuz ? "\n Fuz: " + obj.fuz : "";
mesg += obj.buz ? "\n Buz: " + obj.buz : "";
```

> What I'd like to know, is if there is a better way to write the if statements, if I can short circuit them, or use a shorthand.

Not really. Moreover, what you have with the `if` statements (or the series of conditional operator expressions) is clear and easy to debug. There are other ways to do it, but they may be harder for people coming to the code fresh to understand.

For example, you could have this constant:

```typescript
const messageParts = [
    {key: "foo", label: "Foo"},
    {key: "boo", label: "Boo"},
    {key: "fuz", label: "Fuz"},
    {key: "buz", label: "Buz"},
] as const;
```

(The `as const` is important, that way TypeScript can see that the `key` values are valid keys for `StrObjType`.)

Then the code is something like:

```
for (const {key, label} of messageParts) {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (value) {
        mesg += `\n ${label}: ${value}`;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOB5ARgKwCrmgXigbwCgpioAzAe3IH4AuKAZwQEsA7AcwG4iTlLaHm7LiTIBXAF79G8Vp27FkEqYLkBfAgQDG5FoygBbCPXoBDNhAAKJ+MHpRcAbXn4A1hBB0ARBXKeANFAANibIEIFeAGKUnqp+znhuHlCevL4BwaHhyQBC0bHxiV6kEv5BIWGRJfkiCe5eiuKlGRU5VXEAulAmdtq6wFwEACYQmsHw0IEQwFDkaHRwSGiYkAOT04b0bPbJngMU8FAAFL16tSDp5YGqM6QGRqbmVjb0AJT4zifTAG4mgaI4MzQDkS7WEJCYt0OPz+EDehBEIg2WwA1LgAAYAHRYUAAJHhmlc6Hjof9VGiwcR1KogA)

For a one-off, that's definitely **not** an improvement, and it's certainly not short-circuiting or shorthand. But if there are a lot of places you use this same information, it gives you just one place to maintain it.

But if it's a one-off just to build `mesg`, I think you're best off with the `if`s you already have, or the conditional operator expression alternative you noted (with the `undefined` => `""` fix).

Comment: Really, I was just worried about a peer reviewing my code. Having someone with a ton of rep to confirm that I couldn't do any better is reassuring, and just as helpful, if not more helpful because I don't got to rewrite the function now :-) Thank you TJ

Comment: @jD3V - Don't let rep fool you, I can miss the obvious as well as anyone. :-D But if **both** bergi and I think that, you're pretty darned safe. (bergi's *very* knowledgeable as well.)